# "each of us" VS "each one of us" VS "each and every one of us"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is there a difference between:

"That would require her to send the document to ..."

- each of us
- each one of us
- each and every one of us

Is one of them grammatically incorrect, or would they change the meaning?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're all grammatically correct; the difference between them is **emphasis**.

> each of us

and

> each one of us

Are basically identical. The former is merely removing a redundant word, but it's conveying the same thing.

> each and every one of us

puts more of an emphasis on making sure the document is received by everyone. It makes the focus of the clause the fact that not a single person will be omitted rather than the fact that a document had to be sent.

Comment: I agree the redundancy of *each and every one* contributes emphasis, but I don't think it would normally emphasize the *total number* thus referenced. More often it emphasizes the fact that ***not a single one will be omitted***.

Comment: That's a fair point, Fumble. I'll edit.